# Perl passing command line arguments

Tags: perl, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

I have a program that currently takes either 2 or 3 command line arguments `find.pl [i] <perlRegexPattern> <listOfFiles>.` Now the program will get through my if statements if I pass `find.pl proj1 Data` or `find.pl -i proj1 Data`, however I want to change it so that my program will accept something like `find.pl -i ".*proj1.*" DataA/*`, when I try to pass it my program doesn't make it past the 2nd if statement. I don't quite understand how to pass these as parameters and then use them in my program.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
if(@ARGV < 2){
    print "\n2) Usage: find.pl [-i] <perlRegexPattern> <listOfFiles>\n\n";
    exit;
}
if(@ARGV > 3){
    print "\n3) Usage: find.pl [i] <perlRegexPattern> <listOfFiles>\n\n";
    exit;
}
if(@ARGV == 3 && $ARGV[0] ne "-i"){
    die "\n4) Usage: find.pl [i] <perlRegexPattern> <listOfFiles>\n\n";
}

if ($#ARGV eq 1 ){
    print "normal case\n";
    my ($pattern, $filelist) = @ARGV;
    print "$pattern $filelist\n";
    opendir( DIR , $filelist ) or die "\nCannot open directory $filelist\n\n";

    while ( ($fp = readdir(DIR)) ){
        if( $fp =~ m/$pattern/){
            print "$fp\n";
        }
        elsif( $fp =~ m/.*\.txt/){
            print "$fp is a text file\n";   #Still working on this part
            open( FILE, '<' , $fp) or die ("\nCould not open file $fp\n\n");
            while( <FILE> ){
                if($_ =~ m/$pattern/){
                    print "$fp : $_ : line pattern match\n";
                    last;
                }
            }
            close(FILE);
        }
    }
}
else{
    print "-i case\n";
    my ($pattern, $filelist) = @ARGV[1 .. 2];
    print "$pattern $filelist\n";
    #TODO
}
```

Comment: You call `exit` when more than one file is passed (`@ARGV > 3`)...

Comment: @ikegami I don't quite get what you mean.

Comment: Maybe if you didn't call `exit`, your program wouldn't `exit`.

Comment: I think what @ikegami may be referring to in his first comment is that you most likely are passing in more than one file name with your dataA/* arg. The shell you are using (i.e. bash, tcsh etc...) will expand to dataA/file1 dataA/file2 before your Perl program even starts to run. Type echo -a ".*proj1.*" DataA/* to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is - the shell expands the wildcards *before* your perl script gets to them.

Try adding:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@ARGV;
```

And you'll see what's getting passed into your program.

Given you're using wildcards, it's likely it'll match more than one thing - and if it does, then your program will be receiving additional arguments. Only your program will *only* accept 3.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the standard modules `Getopt::Std` and `File::Find` and note that you can save some `open/close` statements by using a `local`ized `@ARGV`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Getopt::Std;
use File::Find;

##  Parse option(s)
getopts 'i', \my %opt;

##  Show help
die <<usage unless @ARGV > 1;
Usage:
  $0 [options] pattern searchpaths...

Options:
  -i    Case insensitive search
usage

##  Compile regex
my $re = shift;
if ($opt{i}) { $re = qr($re)i }
else         { $re = qr($re) }

##  Walk searchpaths
find (sub
  {
    ##  Filename matches the regex
    if (/$re/)
    {
      printf "match name:    %s\n", $File::Find::name
    }
    ##  File is regular, name ends with .txt, and...
    elsif (-f and /\.txt$/)
    {
      local @ARGV = $_;
      while (<>)
      {
        ##  ... a line in the file matches the regex.
        chomp;
        /$re/ 
          and printf "match content: %s: %s\n", $File::Find::name, $_
          and last;
      }
    }
  },
  @ARGV);
```

Example:

```
find.pl -i ^fa /usr/share/doc/lighttpd
```

Output:

```
match name:    /usr/share/doc/lighttpd/fastcgi-state.txt
match name:    /usr/share/doc/lighttpd/fastcgi.txt
match content: /usr/share/doc/lighttpd/security.txt: FastCGI
match content: /usr/share/doc/lighttpd/accesslog.txt: fastcgi + chroot
match content: /usr/share/doc/lighttpd/performance.txt: failed'. This is very rare and might only occur in test setups.
```